# Windows env variable in Datadog Agent Configuration Files

Tags: environment-variables, datadog

We are using Datadog for processing our application logs. For each application we have a conf.yaml-file for setup:

```
logs:
  - type: file
    service: "auditor-service"
    path: "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\auditor-service\\auditor-service.log"
    source: "go"
```

[link](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/?tab=tailfiles)

It works fine. But all our log-files must be moved/written in a new folder "F:/Applicationlogs". We have set our new folder name in a Windows environment variable: "applicationlogfolder". Because this location can be moved in the future, we want a more general solution.

Is there a way to use the windows environment variable in the conf.yaml-file?

Something like:

```
logs:
  - type: file
    service: "auditor-service"
    path: "%applicationlogfolder%\\auditor-service.log"
    source: "go"
```

If we define a reference/datadog-variable in the main Datadog configuration, how can you refer to it in a conf.yaml-file?